# MySQL: is a complex query slower on a remote client than on a local client?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm wondering if a complex query (multiple LEFT JOIN's, some sub-SELECT's, and some GROUP BY's) is (much) slower when it is executed in a remote client than in a local client.

I always thought that a query was entirely executed on the server, and that only the *sending* of the results is slower on a WAN than on a LAN.

But some queries that are exectued almost instantly locally seem to last forever in a remote client. I'm using Navicat and I access the server remote over a normal internet connection (20 mbit down, 1 mbit up).

Is there maybe still some interaction going on between client and server, while the query executes ?  Maybe some caching that is much faster locally than remote ?!  (thought the caching happened serverside too...)

***UPDATE:***
just did a very big test on a table with 500.000 records with several subquery's and groups (query took 700 seconds), using a SELECT COUNT around the complex query , and with SQL_NO_CACHE and it took exactly the same time remote as locally....   guess it was just the sending of data that was so slow remote then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Only the amount of data transferred and the number of requests would be a factor.

There may be some meta communication that Navicat is using - perhaps running a bunch of small queries.